# Is creating a joining/bridging table the most practical and efficient way of normalizing numerous M:M relationships in a database?

Tags: database-design

Let me start with an example:

**Table `users`:**

```
ID | Name
---------
1, Kirk
2, John
```

**Table `class`:**

```
ID | Class
----------
1, MATH
2, FIN
```

Now, based on what I studied so far, in order to properly normalize this database, I'd create another table, a joining/bridging table:

**Table `class_enrollment`:**

```
UID | CID
1     1
1     2
2     1
2     2
```

Well, it works fine in these kinds of examples.

But, what if my database has 35 or 50 M:M relationships? Is it really best to create yet another 35/50 joining tables?

Comment: If your use case requires the use of multiple joining tables (or [`associative entities`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)), then use them - there are no hard and fast fixed rules about how many joining tables there can be. Just as there are no rules about how many fields a table should have, how many indexes... &c. Obviously, if your numbers of a particular parameter are well outside "normal" ranges, then it's worth giving serious thought to what you're doing - which appears to have prompted your own question. But, again, if your use case justifies it, why not?

Comment: @Vérace yeah this is what I thought...my use case certainly justifies it but I was just looking for some possible alternatives...there may be well around 50-60 tables in my db, if not more...But I am sure people have 1000s of tables in their MySQL dbs, and they perform well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **real best** differs case to case. May be after checking all of your 50 / 60 tables this could be arrived at. Though there is clear difference between 3NF and 6NF for sure, do not limit yourself on this.

For what you had explained, if and only if you wanted to have 6NF satisfied, the third table is essential. And you can have very simplest queries starting at class or starting at user.

But, going that way, for 50 / 60 tables, you will land up with too many cross reference tables which may be worth of having or **not** (depending upon your other tables by design). Remember that you are making all your queries bigger too. Also, being in 6NF sometimes affects scalability.

It is well normalized even if you just have CID within users table. I do not say - stick to just two tables and not three.

There are cases when you had worked with 50 / 60 tables with all cross reference tables in place for a while, you yourself need to denormalize to improve the performance. Though normalization is essential while designing the databases, it will **not** always lead to best performance.

Refer
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization